# Preventing specific packages from getting installed in Debian

Tags: debian, apt, installation

I've got several Debian servers, and I want to ensure that an X server never gets installed on them. Sometimes when I'm installing a package, it has dependencies that include X. Is there any good way to make sure that the X server never gets installed? I'd prefer that the X11 libraries not get installed either, since X forwarding should never be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tip of Raphael Herzog is already pretty good but there is one problem with the solution. aptitude doesnt care about any holds so the conflicting fake-package is removed anyway. To prevent this, one can add a removal script in the package control file of the fake-package (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40800577/how-to-forbid-apt-to-remove-certain-package-during-dist-upgrade). This script (name: my-prerm) fails if the user does not explicitly confirms that he want to remove the conflicting fake-package, which causes the removal of the package to be aborted.

```
#!/bin/sh -e

if [ "$1" != remove ]; then
    exit 0
fi

echo "are you sure about removing your essential package? (y/N)"
read i
if [ "x$i" = "xy" ]; then
   exit 0
fi

false
```

The control file should contain an entry: Prerm: my-prerm

Answer (score 11):

Putting a package on hold does not work (very well) to achieve this. It does not cover all tools in a satisfactory manner. For example aptitude on command-line completely ignores the previous invocation of `aptitude hold somepackage`, installing a package also installs the dependencies even if they are on hold.

The best way in my opinion is to create a fake package (named for example "unwanted-pkg") that conflicts with all the packages that you don't want and to install it (with `dpkg -i`). And then you put this package on hold to avoid its removal.

You can use a tool like "equivs" to create the fake package easily. See `equivs-control`
 and `equivs-build`. A conflicts field look like this:

> `Conflicts: xserver-xorg-video-2, xserver-xorg-core`

You can conflict with the low-level dependencies common to all unwanted packages to avoid listing each individual package (or use virtual package like xserver-xorg-video-2).

Note that pinning does not work to solve this problem. If you do `aptitude install xorg` it will install many xserver-xorg-* packages despite the negative pinning. BTW, for the pinning to be recognized by apt (check with `apt-cache policy <package>`) you have to use a syntax like this one:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/preferences
Package: xserver-xorg-video-vga
Pin: version *
Pin-Priority: -100
$ LANG=C apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-vga
xserver-xorg-video-vga:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:4.1.0-8
  Package pin: 1:4.1.0-8
  Version table:
     1:4.1.0-8 -100
        500 http://localhost lenny/main Packages
```

Using a regexp in the Package field does not work (except for "*" alone, in which case you have some other requirements in the Pin field).

Comment: I think you should file a bug report on aptitude.  Either "aptitude hold" is not properly setting the selection for the package, or "aptitude install" is not honoring the selection.

Comment: There are lots of (old) bugreports open on this topic already, unfortunately the maintainer is busy and can only deal with so many bugs each month. See http://bugs.debian.org/aptitude and search "hold".

Answer (score 4):

http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-pkg_basics.en.html

See section 7.12, "How do I put a package on hold?"

If you 'hold' a currently uninstalled package, it will never be installed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use apt pinning to prevent certain packages from being installed. Try putting this in `/etc/apt/preferences`:

```
Package: xserver-xorg*
Pin-Priority: -100
```

Should prevent installing all xserver-xorg* packages.

Comment: Yes, see this man page: http://man.cx/apt_preferences

Comment: When did wildcards start working in package names in apt_preferences?