# How can I block a package installation on Debian?

Tags: debian, apt

For Debian, I'd like to block packages from installation. For instance, I'd like puppet and superusers to be unable to install `ruby1.8`, even if a package with `ruby1.8` in its dependency list is requested for installation: the puppet run would fail and so too would

```
# apt-get install ruby1.8
```

Is what I want possible? If so, what do I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work.
Insert this text in your `/etc/apt/preferences` file :

```
Package: <packagename>
Pin: release *
Pin-Priority: -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Today I purged wslu from Kubuntu 22.04 for the SECOND time and went looking for a way to keep it from being pulled in again, as it interferes with normal KDE Plasma functioning.

Searching brought up this page first. But an even older page gives a better answer:

[Use equivs-control and equivs-build](https://serverfault.com/questions/17046/preventing-specific-packages-from-getting-installed-in-debian) to create a fake package that conflicts with the package(s) you want to blacklist. Then install your fake package in the usual way. It's quite easy, quick and satisfying.

Briefly, to blacklist wslu:

```
equivs-control no-wslu
```

This creates a generic package control file *no-wslu* from a template.
Use your favorite text editor to change just a few lines of this file:

```
Package: no-wslu
Version: 1.0
Conflicts: wslu
Description: Conflict with wslu to prevent its installation.
```

After saving the file:

```
equivs-build no-wslu
```

Followed by:

```
sudo dpkg -i no-wslu_1.0_all.deb
```

Done.

For a thorough reference, see [The Debian Administrator's Handbook - Building your First Package](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.building-first-package.html).